# My c++ program crashes instantly when using SFML/Audio.hpp (Building works)

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I am using the following c++ compiler

- MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4

on Windows 10 with the following SFML library

- SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-32-bit

and
CLion 2021.2
Build #CL-212.4746.93

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(SFML_Audio_Error)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(SFML_Audio_Error main.cpp)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(SFML_DIR C:/SFML/lib/cmake/SFML)
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics audio network REQUIRED)

include_directories(c:/SFML/include)

target_link_libraries(SFML_Audio_Error sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-audio)
```

And I use the following Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::Music test;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When taking away the line

`sf::Music test;`

the code works normally, when using the line I get the following Clion error

`Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)`

This is my first stackoverflow post because I really need some advice I couldnt find anything online either, except importing .dll files but there were no clear instructions on how to do that. Im not even sure if thats my problem. If someone can help me out im really grateful, I just wanted to add some funny sound effects to my programs. I hope i provided everything you need to know :).

*Edit:

I added 2 .dll files to the working Directory:

[Working Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Rx3.png)

Comment: That error is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. Do you have `sfml-audio2.dll` and `openal32.dll` in the same directory as the executable? How are you running the program?

Comment: Im running the program with the CLion option to run programs. I added both .dll files to the same directory where the main.cpp is but it results in the exact same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue. Thanks to the help of [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja). I put the openal32.dll file into the same directory as the executable (.exe) this resolved the issue and i can play sound now.

Thanks again all of you. :)

[Picture of the working Directory with the .dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwt5l.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation on the SFML site:

https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/

> The compiler versions have to match 100%!

You say that you are using

- MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4
- SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-32-bit

Without looking into what    MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4 means exactly (a web search is inconclusive) this does not look like it is the same as windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-32-bit.

Comment: I checked my versions and downloaded them again but I think i downloaded it correctly, i also installed the 7.3.0 Mingw version from the SFML download website, everything else from SFML does work perfectly fine. Only the audio.hpp is the problem. I could provide the full build-info.txt but its a lot and i dont know if I should just post it in here

Comment: @MarcelGädke Please tell me where you downloaded the MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4 distribution from, then I could also download it and check the version of the contained g++ compiler for compatibility. What I cannot do is install CLion.

Comment: this the MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.4 disteibution i downloaded https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/7.3.0/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-7.3.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0.7z/download